# paint application - python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a paint brush game in pygame. Ive done the painting, but i want the user to click on an image and that will change the brush of the paint brush. If user clicks on blue image, the paint brush becomes blue. So far, I have manged to display the blue image and i have a default red paint brush. The paint brush colour only changes when the position of the blue image is touched. i want the paint brush color to remain when the user clicks on any other area of the screen.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))

screen.fill((255,255,255))

brush = pygame.image.load("redbrush.png")
brush = pygame.transform.scale(brush,(45,45))

brush2 = pygame.image.load("bluebrush.png")
brush2 = pygame.transform.scale(brush2,(45,45))


pygame.display.update()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

z = 0

while 1:
    screen.blit(brush2, (0,10))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit() 
        elif event.type ==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            z=1
        elif event.type ==MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            z=0
        if z==1:
            screen.blit(brush, (x -23.5,y-23.5))
            pygame.display.update()
            if brush2.get_rect().collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                screen.blit(brush2, (x -23.5,y-23.5))
                pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your lines:

```
if brush2.get_rect().collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
    screen.blit(brush2, (x -23.5,y-23.5))
    pygame.display.update()
```

with:

```
if brush2.get_rect().collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
    (brush, brush2) = (brush2, brush) # swaps brush and brush2
    pygame.display.update()
```

**EDITED:** I saw your comments and here's an edited version of your code:

```
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))

screen.fill((255,255,255))

brush1 = pygame.image.load("redbrush.png")
brush1 = pygame.transform.scale(brush1,(45,45))
pos1 = (0, 32)

brush2 = pygame.image.load("bluebrush.png")
brush2 = pygame.transform.scale(brush2,(45,45))
brush2 = pygame.transform.scale(brush2,(45,45))
pos2 = (0, 64)

brush = brush1

pygame.display.update()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

z = 0

while 1:
    screen.blit(brush1, pos1)
    screen.blit(brush2, pos2)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit() 
        elif event.type ==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            z=1
        elif event.type ==MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            z=0
        if z==1:
            if brush1.get_rect(center=pos1).collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                brush = brush1
            if brush2.get_rect(center=pos2).collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                brush = brush2
            screen.blit(brush, (x -23.5,y-23.5))
            pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: there is a bug now, if you go from a blue brush to a red brush and with the red brush click on red, it goes to blue

Comment: @Pro-grammer I thought you want such conversions. However you could use another approach: use two variables blue/red, while introduce a new variable `default_brush` and set it when clicking on the icons. Please let me know if you need me showing any other codes.

Comment: I understand what youre saying, but i cant work it out logically can you show me please? Thanks